# Can't use javascript File object if ionic native File defined in import.

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3, ionic-native

I want to use javascript file object but can't able to use because ionic native file object already has a same key **File**

Look at below example:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage{
 constructor(private file: File) { }

  test(buf){
   let file = new File([buf],'test.txt',{type:'text/plain'})
   //above javascript File Object is determined as File of @ionic-native/file
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know ionic at all, (nor angular nor typescript btw) but if their module implementation is similar to the DOM one, then your ionic's `File` variable should be scoped to your module script, and you should still be able to access the Window's one through `window.File`.

Comment: your can use new Blob in that case                                                    var filepart = ['<a id="abc"><b id="bcd">hey!</b></a>'];
var myfile = new Blob(filepart , {type : 'text/html'}); // the blob
window.open(URL.createObjectURL(myfile ));

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but i got solution for this using import with alias in typescript.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my own question:

We can import with alias in typescript look below line to get ride of this.

`import { File as ionicFile } from '@ionic-native/file';`